# jquery animation (background)

Tags: jquery, animation, background

I'm currently using this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $backgroundimages = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5'];
    var $backgroundcount = 0;

    function fade($ele) {
        $ele.css('background-image', 'url('+$backgroundimages[$backgroundcount]+')');
        $backgroundcount++;
        $ele.fadeIn(3500).delay(600).fadeOut(800, function () {
            if ($backgroundcount >= $backgroundimages.length) {
                $backgroundcount = 0;
            };
            fade($ele);
        });
    };

    fade($('#stretchParent  .HomeImage').first());

});
```

With this code I'm able to fade in / fade out background images. Is there a way to stop the animation (and keep the last image) when it reaches the last image? I think .stop should work but I cant figure it out.

best regards

Comment: Did you try removing the "img5" from backgroundimages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put recursive `fade` call in `else` block:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var $backgroundimages = ['img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5'];
   var $backgroundcount = 0;
   function fade($ele) {
       $ele.css('background-image', 'url('+$backgroundimages[$backgroundcount]+')');
       $backgroundcount++;
       $ele.fadeIn(3500).delay(600).fadeOut(800, function () {
           if ($backgroundcount >= $backgroundimages.length) {
            $backgroundcount = 0;
           } else {
               fade($ele);
           }
       });
   };
   fade($('#stretchParent  .HomeImage').first());
});
```